# DNS forwarding used to point GoDaddy DNS to Heroku app: this doesn't work from a corporate network, why?

Tags: dns, godaddy, dns-servers, heroku

My domain on GoDaddy is set up with DNS forwarding to the Heroku app.

This works fine from all the internet connections I've tried except for the one at work. How can I troubleshoot this issue? Is it a case of ports being blocked? Why might that matter?

Comment: When did you change your DNS at Godaddy? Your work can have a dns cached from sometimes.

Comment: Does the IP is good when try with this service: http://www.whatsmydns.net/ ?

Comment: "doesn't work" - what actually happens? Does it go to the old location (ie. it's cached)? Doesn't resolve? Or something else?

Comment: It displays the files that used to be on the Godaddy hosting server. I deleted those files - they don't exist anymore. But it still shows that when i navigate to the site from my office network

Comment: If you are seeing files that having been deleted then this must be a caching issue (as j0k suggests) with the DNS/proxy server at your place of work.

Comment: Thanks, How do I fix that? Just email the IT dept asking them to refresh the cache? I'm not sure what else I can do? Shouldn't it have refreshed already - its been this way for many days - a week I think

Comment: If its a caching issue you need to flush your DNS cache.  On the client PC this is done by cmd ipconfig -flushdns.   One your corp DNS server you usually just restart BIND or whatever DNS server you are using to flush this cache.  Make sure the corp dns server does not have actual hard records for your domain which conflict with godaddy.

Answer (score 3):

Can you share your GoDaddy records?
I assume what is going on is this:

1. You are pointing a `www` record to your app on Heroku. For example `www.yoursite.com` to `mysite.heroku.com`
2. Chances are you dont have an A record, since heroku does not give you real static IP addresses
3. On regular networks, you are using public dns services like Comcast, ATT or Google.  These DNS services will correct dns mistakes for visitors. So when a visitor types an incorrect domain, they try their best to find the correct site.
4. Your company domain is using its own DNS service that does not have this correction feature.

The above is speculation, but this is usually the case with Heroku, Azure and EC2 without a static IP. If you are using Heroku use a DNS service that works with app domains. `dnsmadeeasy.com` has a service called ANAME (not CNAME, but ANAME) records that will work with both Heroku and Azure. It's paid, but it's cheap.